# Linux set higher baud rate and associated settings

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, termios, baud-rate

Input hardware: BeagleBone Black, with some GNU/Linux distro running on it.

What I want to achieve: I want to set some `UART` peripheral to `921600` baud value, and be able to set the other serial-associated settings (e.g. start/stop bits, parity, data bits, hw flow control, etc).

By far, in Linux, I have found at least three ways of configuring this parameters:

1. Using `struct termios` form `termios.h` header file.
2. Using `struct termios2` from `asm/termios.h` header file.
3. Using the `stty(1)` GNU/Linux utility.

What's the problem:

With the first method I can't use the `921600` baud rate value (there's no define for such higher value, it only goes up to `230400 baud`. So this method won't work.

The second method offers me one way to change custom `baud` rate values, but is also tricky because it doesn't offer some functions like `tcgetattr()`, `tcsendbreak()`, `tcflush()`, and so one. This functions are present in the first-described method, and I can't include both header files `termios.h` and `asm/termios.h` because of [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710525/including-termios-h-and-asm-termios-h-in-the-same-project).

The last method also don't work, or at least it doesn't work for all the settings I want to make. This is the current method I'm using, I'm opening the targeted file, I get one file descriptor, to that file descriptor I set the communication parameters (baud (first i set one lower value), parity, start/stop bits, etc) using the first method, and then I use `stty(1)` utility to change (override) the baud rate value to `921600` (I make a `system(...)` function call to perform this).

This method won't work if I want to change the `HW flow control` for example (it won't override that setting, just like happens with the `baud` value).

What are the solutions?

Is it ok to mix two methods of setting parameters to a `UART`-communication link like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [setserial](http://linurs.org/linux/SerialPort.html) console utility:

1) Get baud_base value from `setserial` output

```
setserial -a /dev/<...>
```

2) Calculate divisor = baud_base / desired_baud_rate

For example if baud_base = 3000000 (3MHz):

```
baud_rate = 115200 -> divisor = 26.04 (approximately 26)
baud_rate = 230400 -> divisor = 13.02 (approximately 13)
baud_rate = 921600 -> divisor = 3.26
```

3.26 is too much to set divisor=3 and too little to set divisor=4.

So, in this case you can't use baud_rate=921600 because of hardware limitations.
You may choose divisor=3 (baud_rate=1000000) or divisor=4 (baud_rate=750000). These baud rates are not standart, but possible.

```
stty -F /dev/<...> 9600 -icrnl -ixon -crtscts -parenb # desired UART settings
setserial /dev/<...> spd_cust  # use custom value for divisor
setserial /dev/<...> divisor 3  # set custom value for divisor
stty -F /dev/<...> 38400 # activate setserial settings
# now baud_rate is (baud_base / divisor)
```

Comment: `setserial` outputs me `Cannot set serial info: Invalid argument` when trying to set the `baud_base` parameter.

Comment: Are you sure that your hardware supports 921600 baud rate? Try `setserial -a /dev/<...>` to see available information about serial port.

Comment: Likely that baud_base is fixed by hardware, so right way is: 1. See current baud_base by `setserial -a`; 2. Calculate divisor for desired baud_rate; 3. Use `setserial ... spd_cust` and `setserial ... divisor` to set divisor

Comment: Yes, the hardware supports this baud value (I can set it with `minicom` and `stty` tools). The `baud_base` reported by `setserial` tool is `3000000`.

Comment: I have updated my answer. `stty` suggests a list of standart baud rates. It doesn't mean that your device supports it.

Comment: Then why the communication is working at around ~`921600`baud (+-2% variation) when I set it at `921600` using `stty`, if the HW doesn't support it? (I measured this using an oscilloscope).

Comment: Well. It means that BeagleBone can variate baud_base. I am sorry, I misunderstood your question. Could you show `stty` command that doesn't work? Does it print some error message?

Comment: I did the following thing: I opened the `/dev/ttyO2` `UART`-associated file via `open(2)` system call, then I used `struct termios` to make the settings (number of data bits - 8, hardware flow control - off, etc), apply the settings via `tcsetattr(3)` system call, and then, the last step I did is running this command for setting such higher baud: `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS2 921600` using `system(3)` function call. `stty` won't fail, I executed the command from command line and there was no output, which tells me that everything's fine.

Comment: The only problem is that the `stty` utility will somehow override the settings that I previously made with `struct termios`. And I'm also confused if it's right what I'm just doing, do I violate some of OS security system? I mean, since I `open(2)` some file, I'm expecting that the current process will own that resource, and if some other process gets its hands over it (like `stty` in this case), shouldn't this lead into some undefined behavior?

Comment: Try to call `stty` before `open(2)`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, using `system` and `stty` from a C or C++ program is **not** the way to go (`system` is known as a poor security practice at first).

After reading you related questions, my advice would be to only *declare* in you main module, namespace or class some wrapper functions for all the features you want to use from both termios.h and asm/termios.h.

Then you *define* them in two different compilation units (c or c++ source files), first dealing with termios.h, the latter with asm/termios.h

If that does not work, the last way would be to carefully merge declarations from termios.h and asm/termios.h in a custom local_termios.h managed in your own sources and include it. This of course leads to non portable code, but anyway as soon as you use asm/termios.h you loose compatibility.